# Swift 2.0 flatMap usage

Tags: swift

I was reading the code contained in a file produced as a tutorial by Apple ("Auto Layout Cookbook"), when I found the following lines:

```
let recipies: [Recipe] = fileContents.flatMap { recipeData in
            // Fetch the recipe information.
            guard let title = recipeData["Title"],
                descriptionFileName = recipeData["Document"],
                identifierString = recipeData["Identifier"] else {
                    assertionFailure("Unable to fetch recipe information.")
                    return nil
            }

            // Convert the identifier string to an `Identifier` type.
            guard let identifier = CookbookStoryboardIdentifier(rawValue: identifierString) else {
                assertionFailure("Invalid recipe identifier: \(identifierString).")
                return nil
            }

            // Read the recipe description from the associated file.
            var description: String
            do {
                guard let descriptionURL = bundle.URLForResource(descriptionFileName, withExtension: nil) else {
                    fatalError("Unable to determine recipe description URL from fileName: \(descriptionFileName).")
                }

                try description = NSString(contentsOfURL: descriptionURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
            }
            catch {
                fatalError("Unable to read recipe description from file")
            }
            return Recipe(title: title, identifier: identifier, description: description)
        }
```

I red the docs and found, if I understand well, you use `flatMap` basicly when you need to transform the contents of a bidimensional array into a linear array.

If so, I don't understand:

1. what `recipeData in` does: I suppose it is just like a foreach;
2. why this code returns each `Recipe` (`Recipe` is a `struct`);
3. why they use `flatMap` (what are they flattening?);

Any help, tips and (why not?) tomatoes is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`flatMap` will also remove the nil values, which is a bit weird if you have used Haskell (for example).

```
let foo: [String] = ["1","3","5","asd","3"]

let bar: [Int] = foo.flatMap { val in

    guard let int = Int(val) else { return nil}
    return int
}

// bar == [1,3,5,3]
```

Answering your questions:

> what recipeData in does: I suppose it is just like a foreach;

A forEach takes a function: `T -> Void`, which is a bit different from what's happening there. You basically have an `[AnyObject]` and you are converting it to `[Recipe]`.

> why they use flatMap (what are they flattening?);

Going back to my initial explanation, from the snippet I would say they are removing the nil `Recipe`s, so you only have the `Recipe`s you were able to create.

Comment: Ok, I mentioned the foreach to pass the concept of "loop", I should have directly written "loop". I specified what Recipe was because I haven't pasted the relative code (I don't know if there's one who can think Recipe is a built in type, but...)   ;-)

Comment: @IanBell I think one can infer from the context that `Recipe` is your own type.

Comment: Of course, but very often I find people asking "and what is this / what is that"... this time I preferred to specify   :-)

Comment: @IanBell let me remove that bit from my answer then.

Comment: Don't worry, you have written what you thought it was the right thing to write, leave it that way, and THANKS so much for your help

Comment: Can't you simply write `let bar: [Int] = foo.flatMap { Int($0) }`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer to your question - but I strive to clarify a potential misunderstanding:

> if I understand well, you use flatMap basicly when you need to transform the contents of a bidimensional array into a linear array.

This may be true for the current situation. However, `map` and `flatMap` are more "abstract" methods which will be applied to some sort of "container". The actual operation performed by `map` and `flatMap` depends on that type of container - or *context*.

For example, `map` and `flatMap` is defined for arrays, dictionaries - and Optionals. Ugh, is an `Optional` a *container*? Yes, it is - sort of.
As well as some generic - e.g. `Foo<T>`. Here, the "context" is a generic class or struct `Foo`. It's "element" is a value of type `T`. The number of elements in this "container" may be only one - or many. So, what `map` and `flatMap` actually does depends on that *context*.

`flatMap` may be defined in terms of `map` and `flatten`. That is, `flatMap` will be implemented such that it takes the result of `map` and applies `flatten` to it:

```
container.map { f($0) }.flatten()
```

`map` and `flatMap` are so-called *combinators* - a term in functional programming. Combinators can be applied to these sort of containers and return a new container of the same kind - but possibly with another element type.

Combinators - as the name suggest - can be combined together and form more complex operations.

You may now read the docs for `map`, `flatMap` and `flatten` for the various types that define it and get an idea *what* they are meant for.